# extract a character and various short ints from the same void pointer in C

Tags: c, pointers, void-pointers

I'm trying to accomplish the following:
given the function:
`int f(void *p)`
take the first byte of p and extract it as a character. Then based on what that character is determine which additional bytes to extract as short ints. For example if I have a certain character c then extract byte 4 and 7 as short ints and store them in separate variables; if I have a certain different character d extract bytes 3, 4, 5 and store them as separate variables. With this information execute some other irrelevant code. I've been struggling with this for hours.

I tried the following:

```
int f(void *p) {
    char *first = &p;
    short int *third =  p + 2;
    short int *fifth =  p + 4;
    short int *seventh =  p + 6;
    printf("%s %s %s, %s", first, third, fifth , seventh);

}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    char test[] = "*5431234567";
    f(test);

}
```

My result:
    ▒▒ϲ -1295010922 -1295010920, -1295010918

Expected:
    * 4 1 3

After a while I realized I was attempting to de-reference a void pointer which does not work. So I tried casting:

```
char* c = (char*) p;
char first = (char) (*c)
printf("%s", first);
```

This gave me a seg fault.

I tried similar things with short int casting to no avail. If this is a somewhat noobish question I apologize. I'm new to C and the whole concept of pointers and references is new to me. My first language was Java which is much more forgiving.

Comment: You can't do arithmetic on a `void` pointer.

Comment: Why not have `f` just take a `char*` parameter, since that's what you're passing to it?

Comment: Formally, you can't do arithmetic on a `void *`.  Sadly, GCC doesn't enforce that, and treats a `void *` as roughly equivalent to a `char *` when it comes to pointer arithmetic,

Comment: @aschepler because this is an assignment and I must use that function signature.

Comment: fix like [this](https://ideone.com/5kQgsB) Also If the function `f` needs to be a signature of `int f(void *p)`, you need to return a (`int`) value.

Answer (score 3):

Your input is a string, and your expected output are individual characters within the string. There is nothing `short int`-like about this problem.

```
char *s = p;
printf("%c %c %c, %c", s[0], s[2], s[4] , s[6]);
```

If you need to store those values into `short int` variables, then you do not need pointers.

```
short int x = s[2] - '0';
short int y = s[4] - '0';
short int z = s[6] - '0';

printf("%c %hd %hd %hd\n", s[0], x, y, z);
```

The characters that represent the decimal digits are guaranteed to be contiguous, so you can compute the ordinal value by calculating the offset from `'0'`.

Comment: whoops I meant for printf("%s %s %s, %s", first, third, fifth , seventh); to be printf("%s %i %i, %i", first, third, fifth , seventh);

Comment: @SamK9: `%i` and `%d` are identical for `printf`. But, your input does not consist of integers. Your input is a string, and your expected output correspond to characters within the string.

Comment: yes but I need to convert them to short ints so I can do math operations with them

Comment: You are changing your requirements. If you actually have a different question than the one that is presented in this question, ask a new one.

Comment: Sorry if I was too vague but I thought I covered that "Then based on what that character is determine which additional bytes to extract as **short ints**. For example if I have a certain character c then extract byte 4 and 7 as **short ints** and store them in separate variables"  I specifically said I need short ints. That is not changing my requirements. I mistyped my printf statement with %s where there should have been %i but I did say I need short ints. The only character that I need to read is in the first byte.

Comment: You are not extracting `short int`s. You are extracting a single `char` from the string that represents a decimal digit, and you want to store the digit's value in a `short int`. Extracting a `short int` would mean you had a `short int` variable and then encoded its value into the string somehow. But. that is not what you are presenting. Your input is just a regular string.

Answer (score 1):

```
char *first = &p;
```

Get rid of the `&`. You don't want the address **of** the `p` variable, you want the address stored **in** it, which is simply `p`.

```
char *first = p;
```

---

```
short int *third =  p + 2;
short int *fifth =  p + 4;
short int *seventh =  p + 6;
printf("%s %s %s, %s", first, third, fifth, seventh);
```

There's no reason to be using `short` pointers. The elements of a string are `char`s, not `short`s. Even when they're digits, they're still `char`s.

Leave them as `char`s, switch to `%c` to print them, and make sure to dereference the pointers when you do.

```
char *third =  p + 2;
char *fifth =  p + 4;
char *seventh =  p + 6;
printf("%c %c %c %c\n", *first, *third, *fifth, *seventh);
```

Comment: I made small yet significant mistake I meant for printf("%s %s %s, %s", first, third, fifth , seventh); to be printf("%s %i %i, %i", first, third, fifth , seventh); sorry.